# Couldn't match expected type of Haskell function

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming

So i'm very new to haskell and we've been set some coursework to create an algorithm using functional programming. So i've tried making a function that takes an array of integer and separates each digit into a list. However i keep getting the same error that the expected type isn't the same as the actual type and i don't understand what that means, even after doing some research on it. I've tried making a few functions that produce this error so could somebody please point out what exactly i am doing wrong and why this error keeps occurring in layman terms?

```
module Cswk2 where

getCard :: Integer -> [Integer]
getCard n
      | n < 0 = []
      | otherwise = lst_numb : getCard pre_numb
       where
         (pre_numb, lst_numb) = n divMod 10
```

Comment: looks like a very good attempt for a Haskell beginner - the only problem is that, as Willem points out in his answer, you forgot the backticks around `divMod`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression `n divMod 10` makes no sense, since `n` is an `Integer` here, and thus you can not perform function application with `n` the function and `divMod` the parameter.

You can call the function with `divMod n 10`, so:

```
getCard :: Integer -> [Integer]
getCard n
    | n < 0 = []
    | otherwise = lst_numb : getCard pre_numb
    where (pre_numb, lst_numb) = divMod n 10
```

or you can use backticks to use `divMod` as an infix operator:

```
getCard :: Integer -> [Integer]
getCard n
    | n < 0 = []
    | otherwise = lst_numb : getCard pre_numb
    where (pre_numb, lst_numb) = n `divMod` 10
```

Comment: Thank you, i feel silly that i've spent this long but that made a lot of sense

Comment: @CadyOG: well, like Robin says, this looks already quite nice. Learning syntax is to some extent like learning a natural language, it requires some practice :)

Comment: If you don't mind me asking another question, i'm testing my functions with quickCheck as a cswk requirement. Is reversing the list twice and getting the same value the only property i could check?

Comment: @CadyOG: you can here try to check if `getCard x == reverse (map read . show x)`, so check if it is the reverse of the digits.

Comment: @CadyOG Some properties that come to mind quickly that you could consider checking: all result digits are in 0-9; that the (not-yet-implemented) inverse function `ungetCard :: [Integer] -> Integer` round-trips with it; that the length of the resulting list is close to the log (base 10) of the number. I'm sure there's many other properties you could cook up if you thought for a while.